# Possible error in privilege description

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits, privileges

I just got [**Edit Privileges**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)

But i think there is an error because say

> Reviewing suggested edits
>
> In addition, users with this privilege level can also begin reviewing **suggested edits-** (which previously you would have had to suggest). These edits remain in a pending state until they get enough votes to either approve them and make the edits take effect or reject them and discard the edit. Two votes in either direction will finalize the action, except on Stack Overflow where three votes are required.

But [**Suggested Edits**](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits)

> You need at least 2k reputation to review suggested edits.

Comment: It says under [Edit Privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) that it's *Awarded At: 2,000 Reputation* - then lower down says (highlighting mine) *In addition, users **with this privilege level*** - could you be clearer where the confusion is as to be able to review suggested edits?

Comment: @JonClements I think was my mistake when change between privileges from 1500 to 2000 read wrong. sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not gain the [privilege to edit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), you'd need 2000 points to get that (at which point you can also review suggested edits).

I think you got confused, you just received the [privilege to *create new tags*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) instead, because you gained the required 1500 points today.

Comment: You are right. My mystake tought I was reading the privilege I earn, instead was reading the next one.